# Delivering builds through slack with Circle CI not working in Android

Tags: android, slack, circleci

I am configured "config.yml" file in Circle CI for Android, I need to deliver my APK to slack channel, all the things are configured as success, and build created successfully, but upload to slack does not work. Here is my config.yml code part for uploading

```
- run:
name: Upload to Slack
command: |
export GIT_COMMIT_DESC=$(git log --format=oneline -n 1 | sed -E 's/^[^ ]+ 
(.*)$/\1/g')
curl -F file=@app/build/outputs/apk/debug/empower_deposit-development.apk -F 
channels=$SLACK_CHANNEL -F token=$SLACK_API_TOKEN -F title="${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME} | 
branch -> ${CIRCLE_BRANCH} | commit -> ${GIT_COMMIT_DESC}"  
https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```

Please help me for that.

Thanks

Comment: Is it working in normal case? I mean try from to push a build file from your machine and see if it does sends to the slack channel. CircleCI doesn't makes any changes itself to the configs. If it works from your local, it should work with circleCI. You can also login to the build machine and check.